# NSString drawInRect how to set vertical and horizontal centre alignment

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, nsstring

In my app I'm preparing PDF document that contains table. All I want to do is to draw NSString inside one of the column header with horizontal and vertical center-alignment. The bellows code is  aligning nsstring to centre horizontally. How can I do it vertically?

```
 NSMutableParagraphStyle *style = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
[style setAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
[style setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

NSDictionary *attributeDictionary = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12]};
NSString *header1 = @"Item#";
[header1 drawInRect:CGRectMake(50, 380, 35, 65) withAttributes:attributeDictionary];
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For an NSString you would have to do the calcluations manually. There are methods available to calcluate the size that the string would occupy and then you calculate a centered position and call drawInRect accordingly.

If you want to avoid that then you could try using an UILabel and try its drawTextInRect: or drawInRect: method. 
(I never did that myself but afaik this should do what you want.)